# Esp8226 with opto mosfet switch LBA110

Tags: mosfet, esp8266, solid-state-relay, optoelectronics

I want to switch AC load by LBA110 because it has NC switch pole and tiny side. I tried to read datasheet, but with my bad knowledge about electric, I can not find out how to make it work. Is it work with 3.3v from output pin of esp8266? Datasheet not provide clearly information about input voltage, it give max on resistance is 35 Ohm and current max is 50mA, is it mean max voltage is 1,75V and normally working voltage is 1 - 1.2v, 20 - 30mA? I read some informations from Mouser [here](https://www.mouser.vn/ProductDetail/IXYS-Integrated-Circuits/LBA110?qs=nnG3q7dUVNxIzz7QSkkObA==) that say

```
Input Current: 50 mA 
Output Type: MOSFET 
Package / Case: DIP-8 
Series: LBA110 
Packaging: Tube 
Contact Form: SPST (1 Form A), SPST (1 Form B)  
Input Voltage: 5 V
```

So my question: is this IC working like another Opto, connect esp pin -> resistor -> LBA110 input pin -> esp's GND? If not, please help me a solution.

Thanks

Here datasheet of LBA110 [LBA 110 Datasheet](http://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/www/LBA110.pdf/$file/LBA110.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The max on resistance (35 Ohm) is for the output side. The input characteristic is similar to a diode, you need to use a resistor when driving the input.

It is possible to drive it using a ESP8266 output, since only 2mA is needed for activation (check *I(f)* in datasheet). The 50mA value is the maximum rating for the input, you should not supply that much current. Your suggested connection diagram is correct. Make sure you use a resistor between 100-1k Ohm.

Comment: thanks, esp8266 output pin max current is 12mA, so can I connect direct to LBA110 input pin? drop the resistor, is it OK?

Comment: sorry, that's a stupid question, I searched out many answers out there